# What is the unit of power spectral density?

Tags: fft, psd

I have an oscilloscope data, I did plot in time domain, so that unit is in volts (Y axis). After that I took FFT. So now what will be the unit in Y axis?

If I will do 10 log 10 (y axis) can it is possible to convert dB? Then if I will do magnitude square and divided by RBW, I will get power spectral density (PSD). Then what will be the unit of that output? Is there a need to divide by resistance value to convert to watts? Then when I will divide by resistance value after taking PSD? How I will convert again to dB? How I will take in percentage value?

Comment: "dB" (decibel) is a *relative* measure. It's not a physical unit! Decibel relative to what?

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/618958/152903